# dell 5570 uefi not showing available drives

Tags: uefi

I posted this originally on stackoverflow and they referred me to here, superuser. my dell 5570 inspiron uefi doesn't give a clear of list drives I can choose for boot sequence, see stackoverflow post below. basically my uefi doesn't come up any thing like I see in the many posts about using it. 
[link to stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969724/newbie-uefi-cant-seem-to-boot-from-my-ssd-drive-embarrassing?noredirect=1#comment104193379_58969724)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the uefi to at least show my ssd as well as the sata hdd, unfortunately and embarrassingly not sure why it suddenly appeared. I enabled legacy boot rom and that listed all the drives including the usb and it also listed a diskette which isn't there. however the legacy would not boot anything, the boot crashed out. see pic. [image]after returning to uefi instead of legacy, voila!!!!, now the ssd was listed as well as the sata
I'm starting a new post, because the ssd os is not booting and hoping for help with that